# pandas group by and log add

Tags: pandas, math, pandas-groupby, logarithm

My first dataframe is this :

[image]

I need to make a group by date AND make a log add on column "SEL"

So, I can do the group by date like this :

```
df.groupby([df.index.date])["SEL"]
```

But the formula is

[> 10*math.log10(10**(df["SEL"]/10).sum())](https://www.wkcgroup.com/tools-room/logarithmic-addition-sound-pressure-levels/)

Anyone can help me please?

First i used :

```
temp=0
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    temp+=10**(row["SEL"]/10)
sumadd=10*math.log10(temp)
```

Is this the only way?

That's a example of output for several days :

[image]

Comment: I see edit, another values in `C` not exist?

Comment: I re-edit to have a example with all columns. The final answer is a logarithme of a sum. SUM from each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new column with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and set missing values to all column per date without last by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
dates = df.index.normalize()
df['new'] = (10*np.log10((10**(df["SEL"]/10)).groupby(dates).transform('sum'))
                   .mask(dates.duplicated(keep='last')))
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't right. The SUM must be on the 10**(df["SEL"]/10) and not on the all formula : 10*np.log10(10**(df["SEL"]/10))

Comment: How looks expected output from sample data? Can you add them to question? Because honestly hard to test solution without ouput/

Comment: @Kwentinus - answer was edited.